# Pymongo: How to insert an array of multiple fields in a document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on `MongoDB` in `python` `[pymongo]`. I want to insert an array of multiple fields in a document. For example: In the below structure of a collection, I want to insert array of `Places Visited` in all documents. I do not know what it is called in the world of `Mongo`.So that I may insert it. **How to insert an array in a document?** Can some one help?

```
collectionName
    {
            "_id" : "4564345343",
            "name": "Bunty",
            "Basic Intro": "A.B.C.D.",
            "Places Visited": [
                    "1" : "Palace of Dob",
                    "2" : "Palace of Victoria",
                    "3" : "Sahara Desert"
            ]
    }
    {
            "_id"  : "45657865745",
            "name": "Humty",
            "Basic Intro": "B.C.D.",
            "Places Visited": [
                    "1" : "Palace of Pakistan",
                    "2" : "Palace of U.S.A."
                    "3" : "White House"
            ]
    }
```

Comment: Your document is not valid. what is the type of the elements in `Places Visited`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you the idea how to do it

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('yourHost', 30000) # adjust to your needs
db = client.so
coll = db.yourcollection

# show initial data
for doc in coll.find():
    print(doc)

# update data
places_visited = [
    "Palace of Dob",
    "Palace of Victoria",
    "Sahara Desert"
]
coll.update({}, { "$set": { "Places Visited": places_visited } }, multi=True)

# show updated data
for doc in coll.find():
    print(doc)
```

which for your sample data should give output similar to this

```
daxaholic$ python3 main.py 
{'name': 'Bunty', 'Basic Intro': 'A.B.C.D.', '_id': '4564345343'}
{'name': 'Humty', 'Basic Intro': 'B.C.D.', '_id': '45657865745'}
{'name': 'Bunty', 'Places Visited': ['Palace of Dob', 'Palace of Victoria', 'Sahara Desert'], 'Basic Intro': 'A.B.C.D.', '_id': '4564345343'}
{'name': 'Humty', 'Places Visited': ['Palace of Dob', 'Palace of Victoria', 'Sahara Desert'], 'Basic Intro': 'B.C.D.', '_id': '45657865745'}
```

For further information see the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) about `update`

Comment: Can you elaborate this line? `coll.update({}, { "$set": { "Places Visited": places_visited } }, multi=True)` **1.** Empty Braces `{}` **2.** `$set` **3.** `multi=true` and the most important the flow of braces.

Comment: The first is the query part of the update, empty dict means simply match all documents - you can adjust that of course to your needs but you didn't mention any query needs in your question so it is empty. `$set` is the operator used to set a field in the document. I updated my answer to include a link to the official documentation of mongoDB

Comment: The last one is, what do you mean by "Match all the documents" and "Query needs"? It will be appreciative if you give example of these.

Comment: Well you have to specify what documents to update - usually you don't want to update all the docs in the collection but only some of them and you have to select them with that query paramter. If you pass `{}` it simply matches all docs so all docs are updated. Query needs --> simply your needs - I don't know the needs of your application; you may want to update all documents but maybe you don't. In the latter case you have to specify a query as mentioned previously to select the subset of docs to update. You can find examples in the documentation - SO is no place to write tutorials ....